# How to understand this crash dump

Tags: linux, crash, linux-kernel, kernel-panic, dump

This a sample crash dump I have from the unit. Could anyone help me in understanding what these details mean? 
Example: `[<c406dde4>] (sys_init_module+0x0/0x1878) from [<c400dd00>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)`
Here what does each value is referring to?

This crash occurs during a power cycling test. It does not occur every time. During each power switch-over, I see acpower_isr()/poe_isr() occuring. Does this is the culprit? There is spin_lock()/spin_unlock(), is this causing issue?

```
[<c41af564>] (rb_next+0x0/0x6c) from [<c40d3064>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0x1c0/0x2f8)
[<c40d2ea4>] (alloc_vmap_area.clone.18+0x0/0x2f8) from [<c40d3268>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0xcc/0x164)
[<c40d319c>] (__get_vm_area_node.clone.19+0x0/0x164) from [<c40d3bec>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x5c/0x1d0)
[<c40d3b90>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x0/0x1d0) from [<c40d3da0>] (__vmalloc_node+0x40/0x4c)
 r8:c400de84 r7:00000080 r6:01fa1060 r5:00002814 r4:00002814
[<c40d3d60>] (__vmalloc_node+0x0/0x4c) from [<c40d3ee4>] (vmalloc+0x30/0x3c)
[<c40d3eb4>] (vmalloc+0x0/0x3c) from [<c406de40>] (sys_init_module+0x5c/0x1878)
[<c406dde4>] (sys_init_module+0x0/0x1878) from [<c400dd00>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
acpower_isr() [105]
poe_isr() [136]
INFO: rcu_sched detected stall on CPU 0 (t=24030 jiffies)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468286/how-to-read-understand-analyze-and-debug-a-linux-kernel-panic

Comment: Weren't there messages in dmesg/syslog just before there? Usually they're more informative

Comment: Unit is not accessible after this crash, so could not get dmesg